# Calling Azure libraries in Amazon Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, function, aws-lambda, shared-libraries, azure-log-analytics

We have this project where due to security reasons and servers being hosted on multiple public clouds (Azure and AWS), the customer wants that their logs should be sent to Azure Log Anaytics.

This is not a problem on the Azure side, on AWS we plan to use AWS lambda to connect to the Azure Log analytics.

Question is, can we call azure libraries or functions on AWS lambda so we can connect to Azure log analytics to push the logs?

Extensive searching on internet, referred to cloud watch code as well, but that's an inbuilt functionality of AWS

Comment: Do you mean how can you use Lambda to collect the logs and send to the Log Analytics Data Collector API?

Comment: Hi K Mo, Yes, so we have been able figure the former part, we are able to push the logs from SNS to lambda, but the second how we push or connect lambda with Azure Log Analytics, that is a challenge. I saw Azure has some APIs but since we are using Lambda, is there a way to call those APIs.

Comment: If you know the API endpoint, there are plenty of tutorials about making api calls from Lambda, just use your preferred library for the environment you are using. I suspect I'm missing something here though, because that would be the simple bit after having already getting the log data into Lambda.